# What limits the size of ext-SDcard?

Tags: sd-card

We all have SD card expansion slots on our phones. What actually defines the Max size limit of the microSD card that can be accommodated on that particular device ?

Answer (score 0):

The storage size is limited by the ability of the controller to understand certain standards.
This means for SD-cards 2GB, for SDHC-cards 32GB and for SDXC 2TB.
Additionally it can be limited by the controller firmware or filesystem limit that may are used by an embedded device.